# How to apply colour in row according to condition in python Django

Tags: python, django

table.py

```
class resultTable(BaseTable):
class Meta(BaseTable.Meta):
    model =Modelname
    attrs = {'class': 'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover row-color=green' , 'width': '70%'}
    fields = (
        "field1",
        "field2 ",
        "status",
        "field4",
        "field5"
    )
```

admin.py

```
@admin.register(Modelname)
class resultAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display=('field1', 'field2 ', 'status','field4 ','field5')
```

how to apply the condition in table. if the status is warring and ok the row color should be yellow.

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting these display attributes in a template?

Comment: we have single format of  table .

Answer (score 0):

you could add a js to the model admin class of the model. and then using ja to change the color of the field text.

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
# regular stuff
class Media:
    js = (
        '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js', # jquery
        'js/myscript.js',       # project static folder
        'app/js/myscript.js',   # app static folder
    )
```

but remind add jQuery is not a good work. use pure js instead.
inside the js file you can select the element and change its css.

```
var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var searchText = "SearchingText";
var found;

for (var i = 0; i < aTags.length; i++) {
    if (aTags[i].textContent == searchText) {
        found = aTags[i];
        break;
    }
 }
```

// Use `found`.

Comment: @Maddi this solution difficult for me ...because i have only knowledge in python Django

Comment: it's not difficult at all. `found.style.color = 'red';`